# Getting data from database

Tags: mysql, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to retrieve data from database in Primefaces datatable. My database table name is dept and it has two columns `id` (int not null primary key) and `name` (varchar 255 not null). I'm using `println` to show size of records. But after starting project nothing show up. In database table are 2 records.

**DeptTest.java**

```java
package logon;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@ViewScoped
@SessionScoped
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean(name = "depTest")
public class DeptTest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final ArrayList<Department> orderList = new ArrayList<Department>();

    public ArrayList<Department> getOrderList() {
        return orderList;
    }

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "Webbeans_RESOURCE_LOCAL")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public List<Department> getDeptList() {
        return deptList;
    }

    public void setDeptList(List<Department> deptList) {
        this.deptList = deptList;
    }

    public List<Department> deptList = new ArrayList();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        // Read the existing entries and write to console
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Dept d");
        deptList = q.getResultList();
        System.out.println("Size dept: " + deptList.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your primeface relate(JSP) code? what u get in `System.out.println`?

Comment: try "SELECT id FROM Dept d" :) , u are missing id in select statement

Comment: He doesnt need SELECT id since he is using something like Hibernate i guess. Check if you get something from database ( make sure that println gets something ). Also make sure to remove one of annotations ( ViewScoped, SessionScoped i would recommend you to use ViewScoped, check explanation at http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html ). In you .xhtml check if deptList is not null. Better post us .xhtml code here. Good luck.

Comment: Why do you have both `@ViewScoped` and `@SessionScoped` (which is not even the JSF type)?